# algorithm for find lowest subsequence of items in 2 sets

Tags: python, algorithm

N item are in a queue.

There are two set with same capacity.

Each item in this queue must to enter the set that the item in front of him entered unless we spend a certain amount

We want to placed items in those set in such a way that we do not placed item in each set more than its capacity.
Also have the lowest cost.

cost = [a1, a2, a3, ..., an]

This is my brute force solution

```
def solve(i, h, current):
    if i > n:
        return 0

    if h1 == C:
        if current == 1:
            return cost[i - 1]
        else:
            return 0
    elif i - h1 - 1 == C:
        if current == 1:
            return 0
        else:
            return cost[i - 1]
    else:
        if current == 1:
            return min(solve(i + 1, h1 + 1, 1), solve(i + 1, h1, 2) + cost[i - 1])
        else:
            return min(solve(i + 1, h1 + 1, 1) + cost[i - 1], solve(i + 1, h1, 2))
```

I need a o(n^3) algorithm.

Comment: Does your brute force code work or nit?
what is the provlem with it?
what do you want ?
what is your question?

Comment: Memoization with position-in-queue, free-in-1, free-in-2 variables? That looks like it would produce an order of N^3.

Comment: Funny. This problem sounds like it has many real-life applications... And cinema queues are definition not one of them ;-p

Comment: You appear to have already found some kind of recurrence formula, given in your last four lines: `dp(n, i, B, h1, current_hall) == min(dp(n, B, i + 1, h1 + 1, 1), dp(n, B, i + 1, h1, 2) + cost[i - 1]) if current_hall == 1 else min(dp(n, B, i + 1, h1 + 1, 1) + cost[i - 1], dp(n, B, i + 1, h1, 2))`. That's most of the work. Now use that recurrence formula to fill an appropriate array with all the intermediary values and use that array in the recurrence rather than a recursive call.

Comment: Note that you sometimes write `dp(n, i, B, ...)` and sometimes `dp(n, B, i, ...)`, I suppose the B <-> i inversion is a mistake?

Comment: Why have you edited out your entire question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you’ve granted Stack Exchange the rights to the content you post under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 licence](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), regardless of any changes you may make. Vandalizing your posts will result in the edit being reverted, and continuous vandalism may lead to your post being [locked](//stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts).

Comment: Regardless of any dubious licensing, it's always frustrating for the people who have read your question and thought about it, and someone even answered it, if you erase it afterwards! It was a great question and we enjoyed thinking about it. Don't delete it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vaguely pythonish pseudocode:

```
cinema(n,B,cost):
    return solve(n,0,B,B,cost)

# + memoize this
solve(n,i,cap1,cap2,cost):
    #for extra symmetry cap1 is always the last used hall
    if n==i:
        return 0
    cost_to_switch = cost[i] + solve(n, i+1, cap2-1, cap1, cost)
    if cap1==0:
        return cost_to_switch
    return min(cost_to_switch, solve(n, i+1, cap1-1, cap2, cost))
```

This would become DP with memoization (suggested search: m. or m. python). Basically if you call the function with the same arguments, you should return the previously computed value and not compute it again.

Python has some existing facilities for memoization, you can use those. Or you can roll your own.

Assuming it will go through all posible values of i, cap1, cap2 for N each (well, up to 2N for cap1 and cap2) and a O(1) memoization lookup, this should be `O(N³)`